# Jenkins not auto-updating text in console after upgrade

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

After upgrading Jenkins from 1.547 to 1.583, when viewing a job's Console Output, it stopped updating the text automatically. That is, in order to see the latest text, I now have to continuously refresh the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was with the plugin [TimeStamper](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Timestamper).

It needed to be upgraded to 1.5.13, and the issue was documented here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-23867

I am posting the solution here so that others will know what to do.